# Pattern match in a text column

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, t-sql, sql-server-2008, pattern-matching

I have a text column and the data in the text columns are as below:

```
Rob goes to school,get punished
Rob goes to school
Rob does not goes to school,get punished
```

When trying to write a query using case statement like

```
CASE 
    WHEN (PATINDEX('%Rob goes to school%',value) > 0) OR
         (PATINDEX('%Rob is ill%',value) > 0 ) AND
         (PATINDEX(%get punished%',value) > 0) THEN
           'DONE'
```

It should select only the 1st statement but instead it is picking both the 1st and 2nd statement with 'DONE'. Any suggestion how to do a pattern match in this case?
I am using SQL Sever 2005/2008

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please note the FAQs about voting and reputation. since you have 5 questions and have never voted or accepted any answers. http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/7237/27535

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Operator precedenc](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190276.aspx)e and not enough parenthesis probably

You have `x OR y AND z` which is actually `x OR (y AND z)`. Do you want want `(x OR y) AND z`?

- The 2nd statement give `true OR (false AND false)` which gives `true`
- You want `(true OR false) AND false` to give `false`

So the SQL should be

```
CASE WHEN
   (
      PATINDEX('%Rob goes to school%', value) > 0
      OR
      PATINDEX('%Rob is ill%', value) > 0
   )
   AND
   (PATINDEX(%get punished%', value) > 0) THEN 'DONE'
...
```

Comment: @palum you're welcome. Please vote up and/or accept my answer then (the up and the tick on the left). See http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7237/how-does-reputation-work

Answer (score 0):

PATINDEX does not treat your strings as delimited lists (comma-separated values) -- it searches for a match against the entire string.

Rob goes to school,get punished
Rob goes to school

PATINDEX('%Rob goes to school%',value) > 0 evaluates to true for both of them because the [wildcard % matches any string of 0 or more characters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179859.aspx).  Your second and third patterns never get evaluated.

```
If you want to test which pattern is returning true, try this:
CASE 
    WHEN (PATINDEX('%Rob goes to school%',value) > 0) THEN 'Pattern 1'
    WHEN (PATINDEX('%Rob is ill%',value) > 0 ) THEN 'Pattern 2'
    WHEN (PATINDEX('%get punished%',value) > 0) THEN 'Pattern 3'
    ELSE 'No Match Found' END
```

If you want a pattern to match the first value, but not the second, then look for `(PATINDEX('%Rob goes to school,%',value) > 0)` with the comma instead.

Otherwise -- if you're wanting to treat the strings like comma-separated values, PATINDEX is not your best tool for that.  Other options might include converting your strings to tables via table-value function, or what have you.

Comment: It looks like OP knows what strings should match. But it's actually and AND/OR precedence issue that is messing with the boolean logic

Comment: @gbn -- I didn't even think about that possibility -- good observation.